# Where should I be looking for reverse tree traversal of an lxml.etree?

Tags: python, iterator, lxml, tree-traversal

I'm not sure of the name of the exact type of traversal I want to do, but basically I want to read the document element by element in reverse order from the current element.

The `iterdescendants()` method doesn't seem to do anything, and the `iterancestors()` method doesn't walk into the subelements, it just steps up and out, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Can you provide an example? What would the input XML look like and in which order would the elements be traversed?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
import lxml.etree as et

xmldata = """
<data>
    <mango>1</mango>
    <kiwi>2</kiwi>
    <banana>3</banana>
    <plum>4</plum>
</data>
"""

tree = et.fromstring(xmldata)

el = tree.find('plum')
print el.text

while True:
    el = el.getprevious()
    if el is None:
        break
    print el.text
```

**Result:**

```
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I don't think I explained it too well originally, but basically it should getprevious, and if getprevious is None it should getparent, if getoarent is none it should return None. I've written a simple function to handle this, but it seems like something that should be built in and I hate reinventing wheels.